# How long is needed to change trains in Kenitra, Morocco

Tags: trains, morocco

I'm planning to travel by train from Tangier to Fes in October.  The [ONCF website](https://www.oncf-voyages.ma/resultats-disponibilites) lists two options:

- catch the high-speed 'Al Boraq' train to Kenitra, where you have to make a 12 minute connection; or
- catch a direct train the whole way, which takes about an hour longer and is at a slightly inconvenient time.

Presumably if ONCF shows an option with a 12 minute connection, it is possible to make this connection if everything is running smoothly.  But how reliable are the high-speed trains in Morocco?  Is it likely to be delayed?  And if it is, how likely is it that we'll be able to buy a ticket at Kenitra station for the next slow train to Fes?  (I'm not concerned about the cost of having to buy a new ticket.)

Answer (score 3):

I've had mixed advice.

- [The man in seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/train-travel-in-morocco.htm) lists 'taking an *Al Boraq* high-speed train from Tangier to Kenitra and changing onto a classic *Al Atlas* train eastwards to Fes' as a sensible option.
- One of the support team at [rail.ninja](https://rail.ninja/) says 'we recommend that you take one train without transfers'.
- A friend of a friend who used to live in Morocco said 'when we lived there, trains were notoriously late.  Don't rely on making a connection'.  However, he added the caveat that the high-speed service (which didn't exist when he lived there) seems much more reliable, and as that's the first train, it *may* be okay.

I think given these comments, I'll go for the slower direct train.

Comment: You can safely ignore anything Rail.Ninja claims. Those people are scammers that have little knowledge about trains, but assume you have even less...

Comment: @KristvanBesien – other dealings with Rail.Ninja in the last week leave me agreeing with you 100%.

Answer (score 1):

!2 minuts should be 10 more than you need if everything is on time. And you would not expect a railway would force you to buy a new ticket when you miss a connection due to a delayed train.